# What does it mean to provide a static reference in the context of a Java Program?

Tags: java, class, oop, service, static

Let's say I'm working on a class called `ItemService` and I am asked to create those methods inside `ItemService`:

```
public void addItem(String param1, String param2)
public Item getItem(String param1)
public Collection<Item> getAllItems()
```

It starts getting confusing, when I am asked to provide a static reference and when I am said that this will make my service singleton objects, those two things are a little fuzzy for me. I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me. I am trying to understand core OOP concepts of Java.

Comment: I think you're asked to provide something like `ItemService.getItemService()` to return a singleton instance of your class. A *singleton* is a design pattern where you make sure there's only one instance of your object. You can do that by defining a `private static final ItemService service = new ItemService()`, making sure `ItemService`'s constructor is private, and returning the static instance from the method above. Otherwise, you can create the singleton instance lazily.

Comment: Additionally, a static field is one that's defined in the containing class's scope. That is, there's basically only one version of that instance per class. It's the most common way to implement the singleton pattern: have an instance of your object as a static field.

Comment: @MoatazAbdelnasser A static field is a field that is defined as `static`. Not all fields defined at class scope are static.

Comment: @user207421 It seems I've used the wrong wording. Scope rather means  visibility/validity and not uniqueness. What I meant was that static fields are per-class variables rather than per-instance variables. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Moataz Abdelnasser
Are you certain I can do something like `rivate static final ItemService service = new ItemService()`? I am not sure I can since my constructor is private. I understand the part where you say I am expected to do something like `ItemService.getItemService()` that being said.

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN In the time it took you to formulate that question, which may never be answered, you could have tried it and answered it for yourself. Asking trivial questions here is not an efficient procedure.

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN You'll define the `service` field *inside* the class and return it from `getItemService`. A private constructor can certainly be called inside the defining class.

Comment: @user207421 I had already tried it when I asked the question. I was just looking for clarity and I wanted to reach a specific point which is when I declare a list as `List<Item> list = new ArrayList()<>;`  why should I add the `static` keyword in front of it and should that variable be delcared as private or public? Again I am trying to have great understanding there. My code is already working but I want to know how and why.

Comment: @Moataz Abdelnasser Ok, I got it. Thank you.

Comment: I believe what @user207421 meant was that you should try to find answers for your questions before posting them here. This is pretty basic stuff, for which google will certainly do. Just google 'What is a static variable in Java'.

Comment: @Moataz Abdelnasser I got it. I had already googled it. I just tend to value interactions more than reading. Anyway thanks to @@user207421 as well

Comment: If you had already tried it you would have known that it was possible. So why exactly did you ask whether it was possible? Or else you didn't try it, and you should have. All this is the sort of time-wasting that I am trying to train you out of. It simply does not make sense to ask a question you can answer 100% correctly for yourself. You might never get an answer; you might get a wrong answer; or you might get several different answers with no way to choose between them ... except trying it for yourself.

Comment: @user207421 For the sake of time management you are right

Comment: I believe you question is about OOP. We should think of classes as objects first. What object is a Item? What is an Item Service? What a service does? Abstracted all from real world. Lets take a exact item: a laptop. Ok, makes sense. What is a LaptopService than, what methods does it have? Does it repair only laptops or phones also? Can it be divided in several services? Can we have a ElectronicDevicesService that is abstract and has a repair method, and a LaptopService that implements it?
- Will be better for service methods to have objects as paramethers of laptop if it is a LaptopService.